# Issue with php concatenation

Tags: php, syntax-error, echo

I am getting error with the following lines:

```
$get = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );    
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
echo '<form action="invoices.php?id=$id" method="POST">';
echo '<label>Invoice ID: </label>'. $id. '<br>';
echo '<label>User ID: </label>'. $get['customer_id']. '<br>';
echo '<label>Set Status: </label> <select name="status" id="status">
<option value="Unpaid"'.**if($get[/'status/'] == "Unpaid"**){ echo " selected";}.'>Unpaid</option>
<option value="Paid"'.**if($get[/'status/'] == "Paid"**){ echo " selected";}.'>Paid</option>
<option value="Cancelled"' **.if($get[/'status/'] == "Cancelled"**){ echo " selected";}.'>Cancelled</option>
</select>';
```

Error it shows is unexpected If statement on line xx

Issue is with php concatenating two strings.. Can anyone help me correct the if statements?

Comment: What are these asterisks? Your code seems to be very wrong. Try to use something like: `echo '<option value="foo"' . ($get['bar'] == 'foo' ? ' selected' : '') . '>Foo</option> ';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer this formatting:

```php
echo '<form action="invoices.php?id=' . $id . '" method="POST">';
echo '<label>Invoice ID: </label>'. $id. '<br>';
echo '<label>User ID: </label>'. $get['customer_id']. '<br>';
echo '<label>Set Status: </label> 
    <select name="status" id="status">
        <option value="Unpaid"' . ($get['status'] == 'Unpaid' ? ' selected' : '') . '>Unpaid</option>
        <option value="Paid"' . ($get['status'] == 'Paid' ? ' selected' : '') . '>Paid</option>
        <option value="Cancelled"' . ($get['status'] == 'Cancelled' ? ' selected' : '') . '>Cancelled</option>
    </select>';
```

Comment: But you are not using If statement? How will it show selected for saved value?

Comment: Ohh i got it. Let me try this!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$get = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );    
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
echo '<form action="invoices.php?id=' . $id . '" method="POST">';
echo '<label>Invoice ID: </label>'. $id. '<br>';
echo '<label>User ID: </label>'. $get['customer_id']. '<br>';
echo '<label>Set Status: </label> <select name="status" id="status">
<option value="Unpaid"'; if($get['status'] == "Unpaid"){ echo "selected"; } echo '>Unpaid</option>
<option value="Paid"'; if($get['status'] == "Paid"){ echo "selected"; } echo '>Paid</option>
<option value="Cancelled"'; if($get['status'] == "Cancelled"){ echo " selected";} echo '>Cancelled</option>
</select>';
```

Not actually joining the strings, but this is going to help you.

Comment: the $id in the form action will not be replaced because single quotes were used.

Comment: Correct, fixed it.